# Navigation bar faulty with some browsers

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with a problem, which may be actually easily solvable, but as I don't have much experience with CSS, I decided to ask for help.

Navigation bar on my website worked just fine when I tested it with latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but some versions seem to show it a little bit faulty.. Even on a smartphone, the problem is same everywhere - white line in the right end of the navigation bar. How should I fix it? Also, on some browsers the last button on the navigation bar went below the first button (on the next line).

[Screenshot of the problem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8WbH.jpg)

Here is the CSS file:

```
<style type="text/css"> #Container {} #container {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 804px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
body {
  background-image: url("img/bg-light.png")
}
.header {
  height: auto;
  width: 850px;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 38.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fadd75;
}
.tabel {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.tabel table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.tabel tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.tabel table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
.tabel table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
.tabel tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
.tabel tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fadd75;
}
.tabel tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.tabel td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
.tabel tr:last-child td {
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
.tabel tr td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.tabel tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.tabel tr:first-child td {
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#000000", endColorstr="#000000");
  background: -o-linear- gradient(top, #000000, 000000);
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tabel tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.tabel tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

And in case HTML is needed - here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Carcassonne</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <center>
      <img id="header" src="img/header.png" alt="Carcassonne Logo" class="header">
    </center>
    <ul class id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="button">
        Mängust</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="reeglid.html" class="button">
        Reeglid</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="laiendused.html" class="button">
        Laiendused</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="autorist.html" class="button">
        Autorist</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="voistlused.html" class="button">
        Võistlused</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="osta.html" class="button">
        Ostmine</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container">

    Content
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure if this will solve it, but i notice you aren't clearing your floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. When floating items you are supposed to add a width to the elements that you are floating.http://jsfiddle.net/02j2Lzfd/. So what I did is took the 6 li elements and divided it by your width of 850px's. If you want to add more li's in the future just divide the number of li's divided by your containers width.

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 141.666px;
}
```

Comment: NO problem hope you get the explanation. Tried to explain it the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Test this hack add html comment after `</li>`: see : http://jsfiddle.net/7a1x4e4s/

```
<li><a href="osta.html" class="button">
        Ostmine</a>
      </li><!-- !>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first div; div id, img id and class all = header. ID's can only be used once in a page and can't be called class. if you decide to keep it as id, then in css it should be #header

the line you are seeing is the two div over lapping. if you add `margin-top:100px;` to #container you will see it separate.